# Facebook app doesnt get email and birtday iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, email, permissions

I have created new app on facebook and set permission email and birthday. When i click on preview it says Basic information, Email and birthday will be taken as expected but when i run it on my iphone app, it only shows basic information and it doesnt take email or birthday..is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

it wasn't a bug, after got permission, to get email you have to set FBGraphUser to NSDictionary,

For example

```
NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user
user.birthday //can get user's birthday
[user objectForKey:@"email"] //to get user's email
```

Hope it's works :)

Wayne